# Different I/O pins of same PORT of ATMEGA8 not providing exact output

Tags: led, atmega, uart, bluetooth, android

I have written code to switch ON/OFF some LED light connected different I/O pins of same PORT (i.e PORTD) of atmega8 microcontroller. This process is performed using android app by sending different byte through USART.
When a data byte is sent then the corresponding LED is ON.
When  two or more LED is ON by sending their corresponsing data bye then if to switch OFF a specified LED, a specified byte is sent ,the whole LED is OFF.
if i use two separate PORT (i.e PORTC and PORTD) then i get exact output but in this case i can use only one pin of PORTD and one pin of PORTC for two LED ON/OFF.
if i use more than two pin, the above fault occur.
My code is below.

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
while(!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));
rec=UDR;

        switch(rec)           
{

              case 65:{
              PORTD |=1<<4;

             }break;



              case 66:{
               PORTD |=1<<5;       
             }break;

              case 67:{
                PORTD |=1<<6;       
             }break;
              case 68:{
              PORTD |=1<<7;

             }break;


             case 69:{
               PORTD&=~1<<4;

             }break;



              case 70:{
               PORTD&=~1<<5;       
             }break;

              case 71:{
                PORTC&=~1<<6;      
             }break;
              case 72:{
              PORTB&=~1<<7;

             }break;


             }
```

}

please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is you have `PORTD &= ~ 1 < 4` where it should be `<<` instead of `<`.

Comment: I wretten PORTD &= ~1<<4; But same problem occur.

Comment: You need a bracket around the shift, so ~(1<<4). The ~ operator is higher precedence, so what you're writing is equivalent to 0<<4. Have a look here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
PORTD &= ~ 1 << 4;
```

is actually interpreted as

```
PORTD &= ((~1) << 4);
```

due to operator precedence. In C++, the unary `~` operator is higher priority than binary `<<` operator. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Fix this by using parenthesis to enclose the 1 << 4 expression:

```
PORTD &= ~(1 << 4);
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother. I'm facing this problem for one month. At last you helped me solve it.